# Parsing date json response in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse date JSON response in java

"2014-12-16T13:17:27.943Z"

This is the format of date which I am getting in the JSON.

What is the string pattern to be used for `SimpleDateFormat`to convert it to `Date` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
```

This format will take care of both the formats like

```
"2014-12-16T13:17:27.943Z" and "2014-12-16T13:17:27.943+0000"
```

You can also check **[JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)** if you are open to use some other Java's built-in Date/Time/Calendar classes.

Comment: What does that last four characters correspond to ?

Comment: @Chaitanya:- The X pattern is new for Java 7. See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Ok fine .. actually i was seeing a different link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html So I got confused. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Java compiler 1.7 in eclipse. But still it says not able to recognize the character X. Its throwing an error in this case.

Comment: @Chaitanya:- Can you tell whats the error?

Comment: 04-19 02:12:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
04-19 02:12:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:314)
04-19 02:12:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:303)

Comment: @Chaitanya:- I am not sure but most probably you need to replace all colons `:` from you time. Try this regex and check `yourDate= yourDate.replaceAll(":(\\d\\d)$", "$1")`

Comment: @Chaitanya:- Also try to use this: `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

Comment: Ok sure. I will try that out and let u know.

Comment: @Chaitanya:- Your error suggests that you are using the Android so you need the Z format and also refer android doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html